# Method SimpleFormController.onSubmit in Spring4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

After upgrading spring3 to spring4 which don't have `SimpleFormController`, I need to modify the class used inherited from `SimpleFormController` with `@Controller` annotation. But there are some code call the method `super.onSubmit()`, should I implement method `onSubmit` myself or there are some replacement for this method?

Comment: I implement a `SimpleFormController` according to source code in spring3.0.x to let others inherit from, and nothing need to change except deleting the `import` statement. Though it may violate the intention of removing `SimpleFormController`, it works pretty well for me. If someone need my code, let me know and I'll post here.